# Usar Helium para descobrir classes css não utilizadas no Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Estou tentando utilizar o [Helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) para descobrir classes não utilizadas no meu css.

Fiz a importação no meu index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/helium-css/1.1/helium.min.js" onload="helium.init()"></script>
```

Porém não é mostrado o textarea como indica na documentação e eu tenho o seguinte erro no console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
>       at Object.generateCSS (helium.min.js:1)

Alguém já conseguiu usar o Helium no Angular? Estou esquecendo algo?

**Edit:**

Consegui fazer aparecer a `textarea` usando o `async` na importação do script, porém quando eu coloco o link da página que quero verificar "http://localhost:4200/login" e clico em Start ele só recarrega a página e some o textarea, mostrando no console:

> Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Qual versão do angular você está usando?

Comment: @RafaelRotiroti versão 6

Comment: Você está usando algum bundler? (webpack, parcel)

Comment: Como eu descubro isso? Eu encontrei no sources: (window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).

Comment: Tente colocar esse arquivo `js` dentro do arquivo `angular-cli.json` dentro da viariavel de `scripts`. E chame o init dentro do `AppComponent`.